# First log in with windows 8 account behind authenticating proxy

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, proxy, microsoft-account

My Windows 8.1 Pro computer is within an enterprise network. To connect to the internet I need to configure and log in to an authenticating proxy server. I want that every user who has a Microsoft account is able to log in to the computer without prior configuration. (It would be perfect if the users are promted to enter their own proxy credentials.)

In my administrator account I already tried to apply the proxy setting system wide by setting the GPO "Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Make proxy settings per-machine (rather than per-user)" to activated. But this only leads to disabled internet connection in every account and no promt for proxy credentials appears anymore.

So my question is: Is it possible to simply log in with a Microsoft account (without preceding establishment) to a Windows 8.1 computer behind an authenticating proxy and if yes, how?

Comment: No;  There has to be a local account.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to create a local account and link it to the MS account, both automatically. But even then we need to log in to the proxy first to verify the MS credentials.